# Matlab bar3 plot no data tip with cursor

Tags: matlab, plot, cursor, bar-chart, datatip

I am using the

```
bar3(...)
```

command in Matlab (R2018b) to create a 3D barplot. In a normal plot (e.g surf(...), or plot(...)) I get information about values when I hover over them with my cursor. Somehow with the bar3 plot it is not working. I already tried:

```
datacursormode on
```

It doesn't work. Does anybody have an idea?
Here is a minimal working example:

```
load count.dat
Z = count(1:10,:);
figure
bar3(Z)
```

Comment: @Hoki I can confirm that for `plot(rand(100,1))` I can hover over data points and get a tooltip with x,y values on R2019b.

Comment: @Adriaan, Thanks for the clarification. I have to delete my comment based on older version then. It means that jesus_is_king should definitely mention the MATLAB version he is using.

Comment: @Hoki I am using R2018b and for the plot(...) command it works, the issue is only with the bar3(...) command.

Comment: I think this is because of the use of bar3. A 3d bar is made of a bunch of `patch` commands. a `plot` will have single data points, but a bar is not a single data point, but a 3D object